# The FFT result is keep diverging..(Fortran/ MKL)

Tags: fortran, fft, intel-mkl

I tried to conduct 2-Dimensional FFT with **visual Fortran** and **Intel MKL**.
But the result keeps blowing up. How can I fix it?
I would appreciate it if you could answer my question.
Here is my code:
\\\\\
First, I created a sinusoidal wave,

`real(8), allocatable::  Wave_ini_2D(:,:)  ! [nx, nt] dimensional`

with duration x:[-40,40], t:[0:10] with resolution nx and nt, respectively.

And the wave is passed to a subroutine as follows,

```
    subroutine FFTF2_R2C(nx, nt, L1, Wave_ini_2D,  Wave_fft_2D)
        integer, intent(in)::       L1(2), nx, nt
        real(8), intent(in)::       Wave_ini_2D(nx, nt)
        complex(8), intent(out)::    Wave_fft_2D(L1(1), L1(2))

        type(DFTI_DESCRIPTOR), POINTER :: My_Desc2_Handle       !   FFT handler
        real(8):: Win(nx*nt)
        integer:: status, i

        Win = reshape(Wave_ini_2D, shape(Win))

        Status = DftiCreateDescriptor( My_Desc2_Handle, DFTI_SINGLE, DFTI_REAL, 2, L1)
        Status = DftiCommitDescriptor( My_Desc2_Handle)
        Status = DftiComputeForward( My_Desc2_Handle, Win)
        Status = DftiFreeDescriptor(My_Desc2_Handle)

        Wave_fft_2D = reshape(Win, shape(Wave_fft_2D))

    end subroutine
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. We will need much more information from you. More code, the output and the description of the output. Also, the description of the output you are expecting. Note that using a fixed number `8` for your kinds is ugly and not portable. but it is not causing your problem.

Comment: Probably "not causing your problem" - without a full code we can not say for certain